# Linear algebra, eigenvectors problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose you know that A is $2x2$ and symmetric.
Assume the eigenvalues are $4$ and $7$.

> An eigenvector for $4$ is the vector $(3, -4)$. What is an eigenvector for $7$?

So first we let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix}$, next we set $\det \begin{pmatrix}a-\lambda & c \\ b & d -\lambda\end{pmatrix} = 0$.

Thus $(a-y)(d-y)-bc=0 \leadsto y^2-(a+d)y+(ad-bc)=o$.

Since $4,7$ are eigenvalues, that implies $y^2-(a+d)y+(ad-bc) = (y-4)(y-7)=y^2-11y+28$.

Therefore $a+d =11, ad-bc=28$.

Since the matrix is symmetric, it's either $b=c$ or $a=d$ but I don't know how to find out. That's all I can think about so far.

Comment: Hi Zack , welcome to MSE, why don't you write what you have tried and where you struck up? That helps people to guide you.

Comment: @Ram: Rather curiously, if you check the edit history you will see that Zack has given us his thoughts and ideas on this problem already!

Comment: (And @Zack, I would recommend re-writing your ideas so that the only apply to question *(a)*, and then adding them to this question, so people do not have to look through the edit history to try and interpret what you have done...)

Comment: @Ram Thanks, i just edited the question.

Comment: The fact that the matrix is symmetric means that $b=c$. If it were $a=d$, then it would be called "persymmetric".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Every symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors

Comment: So eigenvector of 4 . eigenvector of 7 =0

Comment: An example would be $(4,3)$

Answer (score 0):

Start with $$A=\pmatrix{a&b\cr b&d\cr}$$ since $A$ is symmetric, use $Av=4v$ with $v=(3,-4)$ to get some equations relating $a,b,d$, and use $a+d=11$ (do you know where that comes from?) to get another equation.

Comment: A=(a b)(b d)(3 -4)=(12 -16)> ((3a-4b)  (3b-4d))=(12 -16) > 3a-4b=12  , 3b-4d=-16. a+d=11> a=11-d> 33-3d-4b=12>4b=21-3d (substitute in other equation, get d, then b, then a). And now we got the original matrix and we can find the eigenvector of 7. Is this correct?

Comment: Zack, I haven't checked your arithmetic, but that's certainly the idea I had in mind. The answer by @E.O. is neater, if you have that fact E.O. quotes about symmetric matrices.